# Real time sum every on change and how to process it with ajax php mysql

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

First of all, i hope u guys would to read it untill the end. I really need help for my problem cuz i've been search for it and still have no idea.

[image]

Based on that picture, the first 'Product & Total Product' element is static in `add-order.php` file. And the second 'Product & Total Product' element is created by clicking the plus button. Here's the code:

```
let counter = 1;
$("#add-button").click(function () {    
    event.preventDefault(); 
    counter++;
    let newSubjectField =  `<div class="row" id="products${counter}">
                                <div class="col-xl-6 col-md-6 col-12 mb-1">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="product_id${counter}">Product</label>
                                        <select class="form-control" name="product_id[]" id="product_id${counter}">
                                            <option value="">Pilih</option>
                                            <?php
                                                $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY id ASC");
                                                while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
                                            ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $data['id']; ?>"><?php echo $data['name']; ?></option>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xl-6 col-md-6 col-12 mb-1">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="total_product${counter}">Total Product</label>
                                        <input type="number" class="form-control total_product${counter}" name="total_product[]" id="total_product${counter}" placeholder="Jumlah" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>`;
    $('#form-products').append(newSubjectField);
});
```

So, my problem is I couldn't show total price from all product there. In that picture, total price is only show the 1st Product's price * its quantity (Ex: 15000 * 3 = 45000). I want when I type the quantity of second product, the total price is change in real time, shows the total of all products (Ex: `(1st Product's price * its quantity)` + `2nd Product's price * its quantity`).

Anyway, it's not always have two product like the example in that picture. It might have more than it depending on how many plus button clicked. So, i want the Total Price always change its value everytime i choose the next product + its quantity.

Here are what i've did so far:

```
$('.total_product').on('keyup', function(){
    var data_total = $('#product_id').val(); 
    var total_product = $('.total_product').val();
    console.log(total_product);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'ajax-total.php',
        data: {
            'data_total': data_total,
            'total_product': total_product,
        },
        success: function(data){
            var json = data,        
            obj = JSON.parse(json);
            console.log(data);
            $('#total').val(obj.total);        
        }
    });
});
```

```
<?php
    include '../connection.php';

    $data_total = $_GET['data_total'];
    $total_product = $_GET['total_product'];
    $query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT sale_price FROM product WHERE id='$data_total'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

    $total = (int)$row['sale_price'] * (int)$total_product;

    $data = array(
            'total'   =>   $total);
            
     echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

I hope you guys would to help me for this issue. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: try to show the product on change of the product drop down change.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Is this a JS problem (where the browser does not do what you expect), or a PHP problem (where the server does not handle the request as expected)? Also, the `SELECT` query from the last snippet is highly vulnerable for SQL injection - please have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Comment: @NicoHaase i know that's vulnerable but it's just a practice. i still new in programming. i think my problem both. first, how to mak real time sum in every on change of Total Product and then pass the data to PHP and send it back to called in JS so, the Total Price will shown the total of all the price from selected product

Answer (score 0):

You can try to show the price on change of the select box if there are multiple boxes.

like create a method to calculate the pricing, I am assuming you have price column in you table in products.. ---

```
-- while add the add button try this code ---
let counter = 1;
$("#add-button").click(function () {    
    event.preventDefault(); 
    counter++;
    let newSubjectField =  `<div class="row" id="products${counter}">
                                <div class="col-xl-6 col-md-6 col-12 mb-1">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="product_id${counter}">Product</label>
                                        <select class="form-control product-name" name="product_id[]" id="product_id${counter}" onChange="calPrice()">
                                            <option value="">Pilih</option>
                                            <?php
                                                $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY id ASC");
                                                while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
                                            ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $data['id']; ?>" data-price="<?php echo $data['price']; ?>"><?php echo $data['name']; ?></option>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xl-6 col-md-6 col-12 mb-1">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="total_product${counter}">Total Product</label>
                                        <input type="number" class="form-control total_product${counter}" name="total_product[]" id="total_product${counter}" placeholder="Jumlah" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>`;
    $('#form-products').append(newSubjectField);
});
```

and then use js code to get the price ---

```
function calPrice(){
  var totalPrice = 0;
$(".product-name").each(function(i,v){
   totalPrice += $(v).find('option:selected').data('price');
});

//then show the price in the box --
$("#total_price").val(totalPrice);
}
```

Lets check if it works for you....

Comment: it's return a message ```Uncaught ReferenceError: callPrice is not defined at HTMLSelectElement.onchange```

Comment: write the function call before the clonning and use window.calPrice = function(){ ... }